# Autofixture: Controlling number of elements that are created of type string[]

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have an issue with creating a string array of type string[], everytime it creates 3 values but i want to be able to control this.

I am using

```
 var tst = fixture.Create<string[]>();
```

I also looked into using `CreateMany` but that seemed to return a type of IEnumerable.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the `RepeatCount` property:

```
var fixture = new Fixture { RepeatCount = 9 };
var actual = fixture.Create<string[]>();
// -> The 'actual' array is 9 items now.
```

or

```
fixture.CreateMany<string>(9).ToArray()
```

Comment: Great, thanks, but can I control this on each create?  For example, if I need repeat = 1 and one create and repeat = 9 and another?  Thanks again

Comment: Use `CreateMany` then, e.g. `fixture.CreateMany<string>(9).ToArray()`.

Comment: Is there any parameter attribute if I want to use Theory and AutoData test method attributes?

Comment: What do you mean by *any parameter attribute*?

Comment: He means that when using AutoData instead of newing up our test data, can we attribute the parameters to define the number of elements in the sequence? As in, you use [Frozen] to freeze a parameter and [NoAutoProperties] to... well you get the idea. I would also like to know the answer to this.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks for explaining this to me. I think currently there isn't such an attribute, but you can ask for an `IFixture` instance through the parameters of a (parameterized) test which is decorated with one of those attributes.

Comment: Here's an example of how to write such an attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67713352/6772415

Comment: @nicstella, very nice!

Comment: Is the second (`CreateMany`) guaranteed to be all unique values like `Create` is supposed to?

Comment: [it looks like it does.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iWGmlu)